# Icon not showing in a button

Tags: html, vue.js, button, icons, vuetify.js

The issue is pretty much the same as the title.  I am on Vuetify's 1.5.24 version and I am currently trying to create a button with an icon inside it as per mentioned in the [vuetify documentation.](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons#icon)

```
<v-btn icon color="dark"><v-icon>filter-variant</v-icon></v-btn>
```

But what I end up with is an invisible button that has nothing displayed inside it. I am using the same code provided in the documentation but nothing worked.

I have already tried redoing my installation of `mdi`. Currently, my local environment of the front end is running in `intellij` in case the issue can be linked to that.

Comment: what is `filter-variant`

Comment: @depperm it is the name of the icon and how they are called.

(see https://materialdesignicons.com/ which is the website used in vuetify documentation to where to find the icons.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add:

> mdi

the following code should work if you are using vuetify, also you can look at their documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/#icon)

```
<v-btn icon color="dark" > 
    <v-icon>mdi-filter-variant</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Comment: i had already ran `npm instal mdi`, and the provided quote does get the same  result, still the same empty button

Comment: @shas have you tried: npm install @mdi/font

Comment: i have several other vuetify component on my page that work  as intended, which is, i agree, surprising.

Comment: @shas well thats weird, what version are you using?

Comment: @shas if you are using 3.0.0, then you should add `import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'` in vuetify.js

Comment: i am using 1.5.24, and must stay on this version for the project

Comment: @shas please checkout this documentation then: [link](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons). Its also important to define the iconfont `'iconfont: 'mdi'`, it is all explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the step-to-step procedure is already mentioned in [Vuetify 1.5.x documentation](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons), however, here are some quick steps you can follow to set up the icons-

## Straightforward way

**1. Install material design icons-**

```
$ yarn add @mdi/font -D
// OR
$ npm install @mdi/font -D
```

**2. Then import the library where you initialize the Vuetify.**

```
// Ensure you are using css-loader
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'mdi'
})
```

After following the above steps, you can use the icons in your template like this.

```
<v-btn icon><v-icon>mdi-filter-variant</v-icon></v-btn>
```

## Recommended way

While working on a project, it's best practice to move icons in a separate file for re-usability purposes. Here is how you can do this-

**1. Create a file `icons.js` under your `src` folder and put icons inside it in an Object key-value format like this-**

`icons.js`

```
export const custom_icons = {
  "filter_variant": "mdi-filter-variant",
  "filter_remove": "mdi-filter-remove",
  ...
  ...
  // other icons in same format
}
```

**2. Import the custom icons in the file where you initialize the Vuetify-**

```
// Ensure you are using css-loader
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' 
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { custom_icons } from "@/icons.js"


Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'mdi',
  icons: custom_icons,
})
```

After following the above 2 steps, you can use icons in your template like this-

```
<v-btn icon><v-icon>$vuetify.icons.filter_variant</v-icon></v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be resolved by using `mdi` stylesheet as Material Design Icons aims to cover the gaps Google left with their set in Material icons library and allow a lot more community integration.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/7.1.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-btn icon color="indigo">
    <v-icon>star</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  
  <v-btn icon color="dark">
    <v-icon>mdi-filter-variant</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</div>
```